# Need experienced css info

Tags: html, css, weebly

I have a weebly site and am adding css buttons. It uses html and css. I got it to work but I need to make it go to a link when someone clicks it. I have tried everything and there is nothing on it on the internet....I have tried searching all day and still nothing.

Here is the buttons I have: codepen.io/anon/pen/avOJmz . Can someone please give a detailed area of where to put it and a code? I am a beginner in HTML and need some help from a friend. I dont think this will be a complicated question, but i just dont have much knowledge in this. THANK YOU MUCH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/href) attribute to add a link to an element. In the `a` tags, instead of `href="#"`, use `href="yourlink.com"`. For instance, the button for demo will look like:

```
<li><a href="YOURLINKHERE" class="round yellow">Demo<span class="round">Take a look. This product is totally rad!</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Ahhh, thanks dude! I found it! You are such a life saver :)